# JavaScript confirm redirect not working

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have the following:

```
<script>
    function DoSomething() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    }
</script>

<button onclick="DoSomething();">Action!</button>
```

I would expect that when the user clicks the button, that the page would ask them if there were sure, and then if they click `OK`, it would redirect them to google.  However, nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If it matters, I'm running MVC 4 from debug mode in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#href) property. Use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

To to set the `confirm` in a variable:

```
function DoSomething() {
    var a = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (a) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Your code actually seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/eWgF3/1/show/

Comment: To be fair, I am testing it directly in the console, I'm not sure if it is different within a function like this though I couldn't see why there should be a difference.

@Andrew what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: This function seems to be working in jsfiddle either way so it might be the console.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, but you might want to be consistent with your advice - with or without `href`? :P

Comment: @icedwater: It doesn't redirect. It just goes back to the page.  If I put an `alert('test')` inside the `if-statement` I see it. So I know it's getting there...

Comment: @icedwater Apparently it doesn't matter. :P Check out my jsfiddle

Comment: I'm running in debug mode in vs2012... does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

```
function DoSomathing(){
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")){
   location.replace("http://www.msn.com");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function Funkcja()
{
    confirm("Are you sure?")
    location.replace("http://www.msn.com");
}
```